# What do you call this type of conditional statement?

Tags: c#

```
var testVariable = firstVariable == null ? 0 : 10;
```

This is an example of a small simple code. I understand vaguely that it is performing somewhat of a similar concept of a conditional statement (just like an if statement). But what do you call this name of coding if it is utilizing the " ? : " symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?` character is the first part of the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).

"Ternary" because the expression has three parts, unlike most operators, which are two-part "binary" operators (think addition or assignment) or one-part "unary" operators (think increment `++` or negation `!`). "Conditional" because the expression evaluates a condition to produce a result.

Reading the linked documentation, we see this exceprt:

> Beginning with C# 9.0, conditional expressions are target-typed.

Therefore, the documentation refers to this as a "**conditional expression**".